# Execute root command with no root user avoiding password prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root

I have a script.sh file executing the following command:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/my/data
```

If i try to execute with a non-root user (username = marco), the prompt password halts the script waiting for the input.

I'm trying to configure the /etc/sudoers file adding the following lines, but with none of them works and I'm always prompted for sudo password:

```
marco ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/my/directory/structure/script.sh
marco ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Any clue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need root permission to run `chown`, then there is no need to give the whole script root permissions.  Place in the script:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/my/data
```

And, *using* `sudoedit`, add the line:

```
marco ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/my/data
```

Comment: The solution seems to be correct, but I'm still prompted for password... probably some other setting is wrong on the user.

Comment: @MarcoFalzone Curious.  I know of no option that overrides NOPASSWD.  Have you checked the log files (`/var/log`) for messages?  (Also, just to verify, you did you `sudoedit`, didn't you?)